# link directly does not work in react router dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I created some Link with react-router-dom . and when I click one Link , my component work . but when I use directly for example in the address bar I write `http://localhost:3000/user/panel` It works bad . It means the css and style does not work . I have to go to root `http://localhost:3000` and then click on Link to get the successfully result .
what should I do to solve this problem ?

for example I am in this page `http://localhost:3000/user/panel` then I want to refresh . all thing goes wrong!

Comment: if u r using `wepack`, then take a look at `webpack-dev-servers` `history` option and enable it.

Comment: I believe it's because you only import `style.css` or whatever the name of it in only one place, am I right?

Comment: I user create-react-app